# Secure password storage and manager for server-side software on UNIX/Linux

Tags: linux, security, password-manager, unix

There's a lot of desktop/user side password managers out there, but I need a password storage solution for server-side app running on Linux. Something that would e.g. keep encrypted passwords in a file on disk, but would not cache passwords and use cached passphrase to decrypt required password and hand it over to a known daemon running as authorized user only.

Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.vaultproject.io/ see if it fits.